# In search of an easy parser generator

Tags: parsing, generator

I need a simple parser generator. The language does not matter. It only has to be easy and well documented.

Comment: Rekex - grammar as algebraic datatypes - github.com/zhong-j-yu/rekex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

I found [SableCC](http://sablecc.org/) for Java pretty easy to use, back in the days of my compiler construction classes. A tutorial is [here](http://sablecc.sourceforge.net/thesis/thesis.html#PAGE21).

**Edit**: Those days were a few years back. Looking at the other answers, you might be better off with ANTLR. I'll let the votes decide!

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely going to want to take a look at **[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)**. It's not only well-documented but is considered one of the de-facto utilities for language designers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work in Visual Studio and possibly use C#, look at MPPG from Microsoft, part of the Managed Language Services SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165963(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I'm fond of [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), also known as yacc. It's not terribly hard, but it requires knowing C.

If you are more a Perl person, Parse::[RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Parse-RecDescent-1.964/lib/Parse/RecDescent.pm) is not difficult either.